# Is it okay to have 1 .js file for each html page?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I write it like this? Won't I have issues in terms of how fast my website loads?

*for index.html:*

```
<html>

<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*for about.html:*

```
<html>

<body>
  <script src="about.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*for contact.html:*

```
<html>

<body>
  <script src="contact.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I just want to clear things up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You should extract out common features among all the javascript code you run on different pages.

Imagine index.js has a function to create a list. And about.js has the same function. When it comes to updating that function you will want to change it in one place. Not the five pages you have.

As for speed if every page has a link for list.js file, it will only need to be downloaded by the browser once. It's code will be cached and used in all the other pages requested.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Let’s say I have a function for the <header> for every page(Home,About,Services). How can I change it to one place? Is it a good practice to add that function to every script(index.js, about.js, services.js)?

Comment: The header is where metedata and script tags go. The javascript is utilized inside the <body>.  The browser uses things like src in a script tag, or a php include to find files.. then the browser stickes those files together. (at least simplest view).  If Function A is shared amoung all pages. so in index.html, about.html... you have a <script src=functionA.js> the browser will keep track of what it has downloaded and reuse. Therefore it is faster to seperate common code because the browser will download functionA.js once and use it in every page.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes you can use it like this way, your website load faster. But if you include all the JS to all the files, it'll load slower because loading time is increased coz all the three files load for all the three pages.

Or a different approach.

Try to convert all the three file into only 1 (This way you'll  reduce the repetitive function)
Then include this file to each file.
By storing the file to cache memory, file only download (load) once then it'll be used from the cache memory. This way your speed will be increased.
Refer to the following link:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Try to research as much as possible. You'll get your solutions.

Tick right (✓) if my answer is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was helpful! But if I have one common function for the <header> for every page(Home,About,Services), is adding that function to every .js file(index.js, about.js, services.js) a good practice? Or is there other ways of doing it right?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it.

Try to convert all the three file into only 1 (This way you'll  reduce the repetitive function)
Then include this file to each file.
By storing the file to cache memory, file only download (load) once then it'll be used from the cache memory. This way your speed will be increased.
Refer to the following link:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Try to research as much as possible. You'll get your solutions.

Comment: Is it advisable to have 1 .js file for all your html pages? or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

The pages load separately so having a script in another page does not affect how fast the current one loads.

In my opinion, if you are very concerned about the speed it is more important to ensure that you are only loading the scripts that you need in the current page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

**The right approach is to split your code into multiple functions as appropriate.**

To address loading performance, use a minifier which will minify and bundle all your code (include JavaScript, CSS and HTML). You won't be able to outperform an actual minifier anyway.

Depending on the technology you are using, minification can be a step during your build/deployment procedure, or a plugin for your CMS which will minify and cache your files as they are being accessed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, it really helped me a lot!